# How to Implement GPUImage Filter in Opencv API?

Tags: c++, c, windows, opencv

I want to implement GPUImage Framework filter in Opencv API.I knew GPUImage sketchfilter in IOS.But I want to implement GPUImage filter  in windows platform using Opencv API.

My input image below

[image: My Input image]

Here I want to get below output image

[image]

How will I get above output image.?

Is there any opencv API to get the result image.?

please help and give any suggestions.?

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is an edge detector, like the [Canny Detector](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html).

This will return edges as dark lines, the harder the contrast, the darker the edge.

---

If you're not satisfied with provided detectors (there should be more than just Canny, but to be honest I haven't used OpenCV in years), you can just implement your own edge detection:

```
output[y * stride + x] = std::abs(input[y * stride + x] - input[y * stride + x + 1]);
```

This example will find all vertical edges without using any thresholds.

The horizontal version would be similar:

```
output[y * stride + x] = std::abs(input[y * stride + x] - input[(y + 1) * stride + x]);
```

Or both in one:

```
output[y * stride + x] = ((std::abs(input[y * stride + x] - input[y * stride + x + 1]) + std::abs(input[y * stride + x] - input[(y + 1) * stride + x]))) / 2;
```

However, it's more common to simply use some kernel and use that to implement many different filters (blur, edge detection, etc.)

More details can be found under [Image Filtering (Filter2D)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#filter2d).

A simple edge detector could use a kernel like this:

```
    |  0 -1  0 |
K = | -1  0  1 |
    |  0  1  0 |
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But Canny edge detection perform using threshold value.But I need get the output without using threshold value.

Comment: @2vision2 Updated the answer with a more simple algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.Can you explain "stride" in code.? Is it Mat?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.But It draws vertical and horizontal line.How to draw outer line only  of the edge.?

Comment: You mean you'd like to reduce noise? If so, that's where thresholds come into play (like dropping everything where the color value is lower than `x`).

Comment: Oh, and "stride" is essentially the width of one scanline in bytes (since it might be longer than the actual image resolution for alignment purposes).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like Sobel edge detection. Since you want to do it in GPU with OpenCV, [here is the relevant function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/image_filtering.html?highlight=sobel#void%20gpu::Sobel%28const%20GpuMat&%20src,%20GpuMat&%20dst,%20int%20ddepth,%20int%20dx,%20int%20dy,%20int%20ksize,%20double%20scale,%20int%20rowBorderType,%20int%20columnBorderType%29).

Comment: This is unavailable in iOS, because gpu is enabled only with nVidia CUDA graphic cards.